# How to match space separated strings?

Tags: javascript

but not an empty string?

```
// loop through space separated "tokens" in a string
// will loop through "" - needs update
$P.eachString = function (str, func, con) {
    var regexp = /^|\s+/;
    if (regexp.test(str)) {
        // ... stuff
    }
};
```

The code above will match "" the empty string.  I want to match against

case1

```
some_string
```

case2

```
some_string1 some_string2
```

case3

```
some_string1 some_string2 some_string_3
```

etc.

Comment: You can just split the string: `str.split(' ')` and loop through the array.

Comment: but that won't detect case 1 - only one string with no spaces in it.

Comment: have you tried? `'some_string'.split(' ')`??

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`String.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and iterate over the returned `array`:

> Splits a String object into an array of strings by separating the string into substrings.
>
> If `separator` is omitted, the array contains one element consisting of the entire string.